# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference while making transactions

Tags: java, android, json

I have developed one application where user can make payment using paypal. Transactions are working properly. It is reflecting amount in business account. Also, deducting amount from personal account. But while passing to next activity I am getting Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference error.

Below is my code -

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation != null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        Log.d("paymentDetails", paymentDetails);
                        Log.d("fnf", fnf);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, PaymentDetailsActivity.class).putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails).putExtra("PaymentAmount", fnf));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if(requestCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Below is next activity code here I am getting error-

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(i.getStringExtra("PaymentDetails"));
            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            showDetails(jsonObject.getJSONObject("response"), i.getStringExtra("PaymentAmount"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This showDetails method -

```
private void showDetails(JSONObject response, String paymentAmount) {
        try {
            txtId.setText(response.getString("id"));
            txtStatus.setText(response.getString("state"));
            txtAmount.setText(response.getString(String.format("$%s", paymentAmount)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is stacktrace -

```
11-09 15:11:31.797 11358-11358/com.example.user.boat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main    Process: com.example.user.boat, PID: 11358    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.boat/com.example.user.boat.PaymentDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.example.user.boat.PaymentDetailsActivity.onCreate(PaymentDetailsActivity.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Please help me.

Comment: What about the stacktrace?

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: That's a single line. It's not a stacktrace.

Comment: Please check. Update.

Comment: IMHO, in your PaymentDetailsActivity.java line 28. There is a method which use/parse to JSON Object, and the things you want to convert to JSON Object is null. Perhaps you need a null checks, "if (something != null) {//do your things}"...